# how to use OnItemClick listener when Glide/Picasso image library is used

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener, android-glide

I have a custom listview with image and text and it is loaded properly in listview by using the Glide image library. Now i want to implement an OnItemClickListener on imageview to show the image in another activity.

Adapter code:

```
public class DescAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final listdisplay ds;
private ArrayList<descusers> dusers;
private ArrayList<descusers> orig;

public DescAdapter(listdisplay ds, ArrayList<descusers> dusers) {
    this.ds = ds;
    this.dusers = dusers;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dusers.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return dusers.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    descusers du = dusers.get(position);
    String username = du.loginname;
    String descCrip=du.descCrip;
    String Limage = du.image;
    long Ptime = du.Ptime;

    Viewholder viewholder = null;



    if(convertView==null) {
        viewholder = new Viewholder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(ds).inflate(R.layout.customlist, null);
        viewholder.uname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        viewholder.desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        viewholder.time = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);

        viewholder.iview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageList);


        convertView.setTag(viewholder);
    }else {

        viewholder = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewholder.uname.setText(username);
    viewholder.desc.setText(descCrip);

        if (Limage.trim().isEmpty()) {
            viewholder.iview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            Glide.with(convertView.getContext()).load(Limage)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).fitCenter().centerCrop().into(viewholder.iview);
            viewholder.iview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }


    return convertView;
}
```

OnItemClick code:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageList);
    final BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
    final Bitmap yourBitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, cust.class);
    intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", yourBitmap);

}
```

Receiveing intent:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
    imagedisplay = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagedisplay);
    imagedisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

But when i click on the image below exception is seen.

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.GlideBitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 final BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
```

Change this BitmapDrawable casting to GlideBitmapDrawable.

```
final GlideBitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (GlideBitmapDrawable ) imageView.getDrawable();
```

I hope Picaso giving the drawable as GlideBitmapDrawable format.

Comment: I changed as per your suggestion but after clicking it doesnt move to another activity.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing **`Bitmap`** you should be passing image URL and then load that image url  in your detail activity. `Glide` handle **`caching`** of images so it will load quickly and it will avoid unnecessary bitmap objects mess.

Answer (score 0):

try this code
pass intent in your adapter class:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, S.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("image",Limage);

            context.startActivity(i);
```

get intent in your S.class

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String image = i.getStringExtra("image");
Picasso.with(this).load(image).into(img_meme);//imageview name
```

hope it will work for u